# Weak convergence in $D^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and in $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

What it means:
$$u_n\rightharpoonup u ~\text{weakly in }~ D^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\\
|\nabla(u_n-u)|^p\rightharpoonup\mu ~\text{weakly in}~ \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)\\|u_n-u|^{p^{*}}\rightharpoonup\nu ~\text{weakly in}~ \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$

I have this definition : [image]

I don't know how i must write the things correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $D^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and from where is the excerpted material?